# a4j:jsfunction vs calling method directly from javascript

Tags: javascript, richfaces, jsf-1.2

I'm new to RichFaces. I have a requirement to call backingbean method from javascript. I used a4j:jsfuction to do so but I was adviced not to use this component for performance and call backing bean method directly within javascript like below

within javascript:

```
somemethod('somevalue')
```

within xhtml:

```
function somemethod(value){
 #{backingbean.test(value)}
}
```

Can you please let me know which approach is better and why?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

a4j:jsFunction is better since the "pure JavaScript" solution will not work the way you want:

```
function somemethod(value){
    #{backingbean.test(value)}
}
```

EL expressions like this will be executed when the page is being rendered, passing the parameter will not work either. Have you actually tried if it works?